# Losing Data Continued

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net, datatable, datarow

This procedure is inside of the xsd file:

```
Public Shared Sub AddRowData(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim myDataCol As DataColumn
    Dim myDataRow As DataRow
    Dim ordTable As New DataTable
    Dim newDataRow As DataTable.orderDataRow
    Dim myDataset As New DataSet("orderData")
    Try
        ordTable.AllowAddNew = True
        newDataRow = ordTable.NewRow
        ordTable.orderData.Rows.Add(PrintContents(0),
                              PrintContents(1),
                              PrintContents(2),
                             PrintContents(3),
                              PrintContents(4),
                              PrintContents(5),
                              PrintContents(6))

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "AddRowData")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Before it leaves the procedure I'm checking the DataSet row and I see that the Variable are there.

In the next step it goes to a form on which I'm viewing the relative report.

The Last form has only the Load event, nothing else.

There there is no any row .

Comment: You appear to be adding **two** rows there; one with the `NewRow` method (that you then ignore), and one via the `.Rows.Add(...)` method ? Is it as simple as looking at the wrong row?

Comment: What's the point of having DataSet? you're not doing anything with it.. Also newDataRow.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: The NewRow method does not add a row to the DataTable - it only generates it - so you do need the call to Rows.Add.  In this case the row generated with newDataRow is ignored (as you pointed out), so only one row is added.

Comment: @Marc Yes thats it because i test it with and without the NewRow and the only sure instruction is the one i post it.

Comment: @Greg I have already say in my previous post that i can do my job with another way, but I don't want to do it, I want to use the DataSet (If I finally can).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables are going out of scope.  Since you have declared (Dimmed) the variables within the function, they are cleaned up as soon as your code exits that function.

Try putting this line outside of the function:

```
Private ordTable as DataTable
```

Then change:

```
Dim ordTable As New DataTable
```

to:

```
ordTable = New DataTable
```

You will then be able to access ordTable from outside this method.

Comment: You probably mean to put the ordTable as .... in my Public class (there where i put all the public shared variables) in order to see it from the entire Project mmmmm!

Comment: @Greg. Finally I manage to fix the fault in my code and I have the Dataset in my current procedure. But Please look at my new Post.